# I am designing a database and considering creating a table with just dates in it

Tags: database-design, relationship

I work as a metallurgist and I am designing a database at work - a mineral processing plant - for a metallurgical accounting project that will replace a spreadsheet version.

Some data used is received on a once daily basis (such as powerhouse readings, and reagent level readings) that I currently have in a 'Day' table.  I was considering breaking this table into one table for Reagent_Levels and another for Powerhouse_Readings, as the information is unrelated and would be entered by different roles, and then linking them to the 'Day' table that would now only have a single field (date) in it.   The relationships here would be one to one.  Is this a dumb idea?  FYI the Day table would also be linked to a number of other tables.

Comment: It's a great idea. It's called a calendar table and is frequently used in reporting systems. Days often have attributes like holidays, weekends, weather affected days.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Nick; good to know I'm not off track.

Comment: Although a calendar table is more  frequently found in a reporting system, not a transactional system. If this table _only_ has dates in it,then it's only good for one thing, and that is showing any "missing" days in your transactional data.

Comment: I'm not really sure of very many good reasons for having a date table actually be referenced. Used for "missing days" queries as Nick suggested? yes, very useful. But actually _referenced_ by other tables? No good reason I can think of.